# Django password in PHP

Tags: php, django, database, security, passwords

I have a problem, because I have a database with users and theirs passwords were secured with Django (pbkdf2). So '123' looks like this:

```
pbkdf2_sha256$20000$MflWfLXbejfO$tNrjk42YE9ZXkg7IvXY5fikbC+H52Ipd2mf7m0azttk=
```

Now I need to use this passwords in PHP project and I don't have any idea how to compare them.

Comment: I strongly disagree @Sayse - it sounds like he's replacing django with PHP, so the answer shouldn't be "run both"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pbkdf2_sha256$20000$MflWfLXbejfO$tNrjk42YE9ZXkg7IvXY5fikbC+H52Ipd2mf7m0azttk=`

Let's break this down. The `$` are separators:

- `pbkdf2_sh256` means PBKDF2-SHA256, i.e. `hash_pbkf2('sha256', ...)`
- `20000` is the iteration count
- `MflWfLXbejfO` is the salt
- `tNrjk42YE9ZXkg7IvXY5fikbC+H52Ipd2mf7m0azttk=` is likely the hash.

This is all the information you need to validate the hash from PHP. You just need:

1. [`hash_pbkdf2()`](https://secure.php.net/hash_pbkdf2) to generate a new hash from the password provided by the user
2. [`hash_equals()`](https://secure.php.net/hash_equals) to compare the generated hash with the stored one

This function should work (PHP 7+):

```
/**
 * Verify a Django password (PBKDF2-SHA256)
 *
 * @ref http://stackoverflow.com/a/39311299/2224584
 * @param string $password   The password provided by the user
 * @param string $djangoHash The hash stored in the Django app
 * @return bool
 * @throws Exception
 */
function django_password_verify(string $password, string $djangoHash): bool
{
    $pieces = explode('$', $djangoHash);
    if (count($pieces) !== 4) {
        throw new Exception("Illegal hash format");
    }
    list($header, $iter, $salt, $hash) = $pieces;
    // Get the hash algorithm used:
    if (preg_match('#^pbkdf2_([a-z0-9A-Z]+)$#', $header, $m)) {
        $algo = $m[1];
    } else {
        throw new Exception(sprintf("Bad header (%s)", $header));
    }
    if (!in_array($algo, hash_algos())) {
        throw new Exception(sprintf("Illegal hash algorithm (%s)", $algo));
    }

    $calc = hash_pbkdf2(
        $algo,
        $password,
        $salt,
        (int) $iter,
        32,
        true
    );
    return hash_equals($calc, base64_decode($hash));
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/WbTpW

If you need legacy PHP 5 support, removing the `string` prefixes and the `: bool` from the function definition will make it work on PHP 5.6. I don't advise trying to add backward compatibility for versions of PHP earlier than 5.6; if you find yourself in this situation, [you should update your server software instead](http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2014/12/on-php-version-requirements.html).

Comment: Props for using `hash_equals` - constant time comparisons should *always* be used for comparing things in a secure way.

I think in this case though you can safely use a normal string comparison, since the output of PBKDF2 isn't guessable from it's input, so there's no way to influence the timing attack (and therefore shouldn't be a side-channel).

Comment: Correct, there's no practical attacks on password hashing functions that don't use `hash_equals()`; I do so for consistency and to establish good habits in people who reference my code snippets. :)

Comment: Which is definitely the way to go about things :). Never hurts to do a constant time comparison always (sans a few cycles for hashing), and then you never screw it up!