# Create a django password in a simple python script

Tags: python, django, passwords

I need to generate an encrypted password that can be used within Django in a simple python script. What package/module would I need to import to achieve that? I am looking for something like:

```
from django.auth import create_password_from_string

django_password = create_password_from_string('coolpassword')
```

The background is, that I have a PHP application on server1 which should share the accounts with a Django application on server2. When an account is created in the PHP application, I want to fire up a python script that generates the encrypted password for the django application and transfers it to server2.

Of course, creating the encrypted string by PHP would be much better for this usecase, but I bet its even harder to achieve.

Comment: iw iwll check this, could helpt me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39310898/django-password-in-php

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is [make_password](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#django.contrib.auth.hashers.make_password).

**Basic usage:**

Simply pass your plain-text password, it returns the hash you need.

Furthermore, according to the project reqs and specs, [you can set the algorithm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/passwords/#auth-included-hashers) on the server2 app: just pass also the **hasher** parameter (note: in Django, the default is PBKDF2).

**Environment requisites:**

First of all, if you're new to Python my advice is to take a look to the [PYTHONPATH](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/PythonPath) env var, used to "tell" to the interpreter where he has to search.
Then, using Django, if you want you can define which settings file the running instance has to point to. This is accomplished with another env var, the **DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE**, and for django-admin it can be set also inline:

```sh
django-admin runserver --settings=server2.settings
```

**make_password example:**

Assuming that your Python/Django env/path variables are properly configured, you have:

```
$ python manage.py shell
>>> from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
>>> make_password('password', 'generate something random', 'pbkdf2_sha256')
```

Result:

```
'pbkdf2_sha256$36000$generate something random$0F6M8tj8Y65YXuUgfRkDAwYqrky6Ob5JN+HLPO+6Ayg='
```

Comment: thanks, looks good, but I tried it and got error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting PASSWORD_HASHERS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings` I tried to use the code under `The default for PASSWORD_HASHERS is:` on the linked page, but it also does not work

Comment: thanks for your help but I found a PHP solution, sorry that I misguided with my question for python

Comment: This issue is related to the environment configuration: for example you can set  the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/settings/#envvar-DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE)... But It could be better if you give us more details (for example tha Django version, what happens if you try to access the shell, ...)

Comment: I'm happy you've found a solution, anyway I edited my answer adding the information I think you miss, so next time you'll be fine with Python :)

Answer (score 1):

I actually found an easy approach for PHP, which suits better for my usecase:

```
$password = 'password'
$salt = 'generate something random'
$iterations = 120000
$hash = base64_encode(hash_pbkdf2 ( 'sha256' , $password , $salt , $iterations, 32, true));

$django_password = 'pbkdf2_256'. '$' . $iterations . '$' . $hash;
```

Comment: You help me ! Thanks a lot :D